# Android starting App with scheme and QR Code creating multiple instances

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to get a custom android scheme to work so that whenever a QR code is scanned, it will start up my App. I have this all working, but the problem is, it seems to start a NEW instance of the program running underneath the QR Scanning Program (I have tried QR Reader and Google Goggles with the same result). I there any way to make it jump to the running program rather than starting a new instance

Here is my code. I have 2 Screens (The default activity_main and a new screen called activity_qr that will be jumped to when testqr://test is called from a QR Reader.

Here is my Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QRActivity"
            android:label="This is my QR Screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
                </category>

                <data android:scheme="testqr" >
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The activity_qr.xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testqr.QRActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot that shows how now there are 2 instances of the application running. One which I started before I used the QR code and then the one in the QR Reader itself.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y_F_4eHBNNcTBQZGhCYVRBUUU/edit?usp=sharing

[image: screenshot]

Is this just the neature of the QR Scanners on Android, or is there a way that I can have the QR run the already running instance rather than starting a new instance underneath the QR program itself. Thanks !

Edit: As requested here is a "Desired Program Flow" overview
Desired Program Flow

1. User starts up the aplication (In my Production Application, this is a login screen so in that case they log in are sitting on an Activity). In the sample code this is activity_main.
2. A user will attend an event and see the QR Code and start their QR Scanner program to scan it (In this case the QR code will be testqr://test)
3. The Android scheme will see the testqr:// prefix and it knows to start this app. It will jump to the Activity that will display the graphic associated with that code and handle the processing. In this example it will be activity_qr.
4. Ideally I would like that Activity to replace the screen in #1 by placing it on the top of the stack and if the back button is pressed it would go back to whatever screen they were in #1. Unfortunately, the result I am getting is that it is spawning a whole new window so when back is pressed, it just closes the App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode` tag like below to your `QRActivity` declaration:

```
<activity
    android:name=".QRActivity"
    android:label="This is my QR Screen"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="testqr"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To do something like: `MainActivity` -> `QRActivity` (process QR code) -> Finish QR processing -> Close `QRActivity` with Back button -> Back to `MainActivity` - you'll need to launch `QRActivity` from your `MainActivity` like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QRActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` behaviour is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I run this it does break out of the QR reader, but it is still running 2 copies of the code. The first copy is on the activity_main and the 2nd copy is on the activity_qr. As another test I closed the activity_main and scanned again and it looks like it opens up the correct screen. So I guess my question is When it is on another Activity in the App, how do I get it to use that instance of the app and go to the correct activity?

Comment: Here is the screenshot with the updated code: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y_F_4eHBNNeXZxRGpCMlR1bms/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you want to launch the QR scanning from the `QRActivity` and return to this Activity after scanning is complete? If yes, then you can just add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` to make `QRActivity` the most recent Activity. If my assumption is incorrect, then please edit your question with a diagram flow of how you want to show in terms of activities interaction.

Comment: Thanks again for the response, I added a desired program flow to the original question as you requested. The gist of it is that I want the new Activity to open in the running application and added to the top of the stack so that the back button performs properly.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The launchMode got me most of the way there and I will use your other code as well to finish it up. Thanks !

Comment: No worries, David. Glad I could help. ;)